# How do I insert HTML tags inside a Javascript array that contains pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been trying to make a simple array slideshow with pictures and text and I'm super bad at JavaScript. At the moment I have this piece of code which is a slideshow with pictures (without the text):

```js
var image = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = ["Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png", "Items/Images/PaintedCannibals.png", "Items/Images/Firemen.png", "Items/Images/DynamiteCannibal.png", "Items/Images/Armsy.png", "Items/Images/BabyMutant.png", "Items/Images/Virginia.png", "Items/Images/Cowman.png", "Items/Images/BlueArmsy.png", "Items/Images/BlueVirginia.png", "Items/Images/Worm.png", "Items/Images/EndBoss.png"];
var imageIndex = 1;

function changeImageNext() {

  image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;

  if (imageIndex > imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }

}

function changeImagePrev() {

  image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex--;

  if (imageIndex > imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Next" id="nextButton" onclick="changeImageNext();">
<input type="button" value="Prev" id="prevButton" onclick="changeImagePrev();">
<img src="Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png" id="mainImage">
```

Now, what I'd like to have is this array of images and a description of each one of these pictures/monsters (so basically, *I think*, another array linked to the same buttons). So when you'd press on the Next / Prev buttons you'd get some text for each one of these pictures.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or maybe other ways to do this with pure Javascript?

Comment: Are you using this just as a tool to display your information locally, such as a presentation, or are you attempting to use this as part of a live web site? I ask because there are different methods for each.

Comment: For example, if used for a local presentation only, you don't need an array of image sources or text and could just place it all in the HTML and use the buttons to vary which set of elements are visible at any one time.  This way, all the images would be loaded before you start to run the slideshow, so you won't have to wait as each loads; and you don't have to hold textual descriptions in an array.

Comment: Hi! It's just for an assignment, so the annoying thing is that I have to do it like I wrote in the description, even though that sounds a bit silly. In the end, I'm pretty sure I will have to upload it on the FTP server though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a separate div for the text and use a two dimensional array: An array (a) which holds elements which are arrays (b) consisting of two elements, the reference to the image and the text.
You can then skip through the array a and fill the link and text on the page by accessing the elements of array b accordingly:

```
var text = document.getElementById("mainText");
var image = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = [["Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png", "A Cannibal"], ["Items/Images/PaintedCannibals.png", "A painted cannibal"],["Items/Images/Firemen.png", "A Fireman"],["Items/Images/DynamiteCannibal.png", "A dynamite"],["Items/Images/Armsy.png", "A comment"],["Items/Images/BabyMutant.png", "A mutant"], ["Items/Images/Virginia.png", "Virginia"], ["Items/Images/Cowman.png", "Cowman"], ["Items/Images/BlueArmsy.png", "Blue"],["Items/Images/BlueVirginia.png", "Blue virginia"], ["Items/Images/Worm.png", "Worms!"], ["Items/Images/EndBoss.png", "Endboss"]];
var imageIndex = 1;
function changeImageNext(){
    image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex][0]);
    text.innerHTML = imageArray[imageIndex][1];
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

function changeImagePrev(){
    image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex][0]);
    text.innerHTML = imageArray[imageIndex][1];
    imageIndex--;
    if (imageIndex < 0) {
        imageIndex = imageArray.length-1;
    }
}

<input type="button" value="Next" id="nextButton" onclick="changeImageNext();">
<input type="button" value="Prev" id="prevButton" onclick="changeImagePrev();">
<img src="Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png" id="mainImage"><br />
<div id="mainText">A Cannibal</div>
```

Comment: the overhead on an array of objects is less than an array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

For a first attempt, this isn't too bad.  You have an idea of what you want to do, and how to do it.  Having said that, there are a few issues with your implementation:

Firstly, you are doing things out of order.  You are setting the image, and then changing the image index.  You should change the image index first, and then show the new image.  Simply put this line at the bottom of your functions, not at the top:

```
image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
```

Secondly, you are initialising your array index with a value of 1.  As you are using SkinnyCannibals.png in the HTML, it should be initialised with a zero, because element zero in the array is the initial image.

Thirdly, you have a copy/paste error.  In the changeImageNext function, you have a check to ensure that your index isn't out of bounds, and if it is, jump back to the start of the list.  You have copied this code into changeImagePrev, but it won't work there without alteration.

Here is your whole code, with some corrections:

```
    var image = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var imageArray = ["Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png", "Items/Images/PaintedCannibals.png","Items/Images/Firemen.png","Items/Images/DynamiteCannibal.png","Items/Images/Armsy.png","Items/Images/BabyMutant.png", "Items/Images/Virginia.png", "Items/Images/Cowman.png", "Items/Images/BlueArmsy.png","Items/Images/BlueVirginia.png", "Items/Images/Worm.png", "Items/Images/EndBoss.png"];
            var imageIndex = 0;

            function changeImageNext(){
                imageIndex++;

                if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
                    imageIndex = 0;
                }
                image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
            }

            function changeImagePrev(){
               imageIndex--;

               if (imageIndex < 0) {
                  imageIndex = (imageArray.length - 1);
               }
               image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
            }
```

Hope this helps!  As I said - your code was a good start, it just needed some tweaks ;)

Comment: This would be better if it also would show how to deal with text synchronized with the image name.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an object you can get both the image name and description.
You can then set both from that element in the object array.

```js
var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var showtext = document.getElementById("showtext");
var imageArray = [{
  image: "Items/Images/SkinnyCannibals.png",
  description: "Skinnly Canibals we need!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/PaintedCannibals.png",
  description: "Nice colors!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/Firemen.png",
  description: "Firemen have hot hands!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/DynamiteCannibal.png",
  description: "Boom!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/Armsy.png",
  description: "Aramsy is cool!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/BabyMutant.png",
  description: "Not a baby seal"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/Virginia.png",
  description: "Virginia, good name"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/Cowman.png",
  description: "Yee haa cowboy"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/BlueArmsy.png",
  description: "Blue us!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/BlueVirginia.png",
  description: "Blue Virgina dang!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/Worm.png",
  description: "Worm bait!"
}, {
  image: "Items/Images/EndBoss.png",
  description: "Get bossy"
}];
//set to first image initially;
var imageIndex = 0;
showThisOne(imageArray[imageIndex], imageIndex);

function showThisOne(thing, index) {
  mainImage.setAttribute("src", thing.image);
  mainImage.setAttribute("alt", "On image:" + index);
  showtext.textContent = thing.description;
}

function changeImage(button) {
  let direction = button.value;

  if (direction == "next") imageIndex++;
  if (direction == "prev") imageIndex--;
  //console.log(direction, imageIndex, direction == "next", imageArray.length);
  if (imageIndex < 0) {
    imageIndex = imageArray.length - 1;
  }
  if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
  showThisOne(imageArray[imageIndex], imageIndex);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="prev" id="nextButton" onclick="changeImage(this);"><< Prev</button>
<button type="button" value="next" id="prevButton" onclick="changeImage(this);">Next >></button>
<div class="mythings">
  <img alt="here" id="mainImage">
  <div id="showtext">not set</div>
</div>
```